# tapply() and acast() are super slow and memory consuming when grouping by two variables

Tags: r, reshape2, sqldf, tapply

I just noticed that `tapply()` and `reshape2::acast()` are super slow and memory consuming in scenario when grouping by two variables!

See this example:

```
#download data and functions for monitoring time & memory
download.file("http://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~ttel5535/pub/so/tapply,reshape2_slow/tapply,reshape_slow.Rdata", "tapply,reshape_slow.Rdata", mode="wb")
load(file = "tapply,reshape_slow.Rdata")

require(reshape2)
mstart()
xx <- acast(bb, fi ~ gi, sum, value.var = "hour")
mstop()
#   user  system elapsed 
#   6.58    0.79    7.90 
#max memory used: 911.2Mb.
```

Surprisingly very slow and memory greedy! Just to show properties of the data:

```
nrow(bb)
#[1] 9467
dim(xx)
#[1] 4850 1492
print(object.size(xx), units = "Mb")
#28 Mb
```

Now `tapply()`:

```
mstart()
xx2 <- tapply(bb$hour, list(bb$fi, bb$gi), sum, default = 0)
mstop()
#   user  system elapsed 
#   6.45    2.36    9.44 
#max memory used: 1135.9Mb.
```

Even slower and more memory greedy!

Now, to compare, solution when grouping is done by SQLite and acast() is used only for the reshaping:

```
require(sqldf)
mstart()
xx3_0 <- sqldf("select fi, gi, sum(hour) as sum from bb group by fi, gi")
xx3 <- acast(xx3_0, fi ~ gi, fill = 0, value.var = "sum")
mstop()
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.22    0.05    0.28 
#max memory used: 174.1Mb.
```

Normally, I'm using sqldf for almost every data operations, but now I wanted to make it "easier" by using basic functions :-) But now I am really surprised that these functions perform really bad! Didn't anyone notice yet? Or am I using them wrong?

Comment: That's probably one of the reasons that `reshape2` is depricated and no longer being maintained. The author is now invested in `tidyverse`

Comment: @Sotos oh, really? I didn't know! Thanks! Would be curious how tidyverse would perform.

Comment: ... @Sotos there's actually no info about deprecation and lack of maintenance here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reshape2/index.html . Is it just unofficial information which you present?

Comment: Much better than everything you tried so far without it :). But for even more efficient than the 'verse is `data.table`.

Comment: Not seen it officially by CRAN (not sure If they would 'announce it' anyway)

Comment: Reshape2 is still used by ggplot2 which is why it's still on CRAN. But reshape2 is otherwise retired https://github.com/hadley/reshape